# How to move methods to external file in windows form C#

Tags: c#, forms, file, methods, external

newbie question :(

I'm making a program using windows forms and i have a lot of small methods like this

```
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Select();
    }

    private void label13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox13.Select();
    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        plotGraph(prostokat);
    }
```

in the Form1.cs file and to make the code more transparent, I would like to move these small methods out somewhere to an external file (class?) but I don't really know how to do this. If they were normal methods I would just make a class and create an object of that class and just call the methods using that object but these are functions that "happen" when a user action is performed i.e. a textbox is clicked, so I'm not sure how to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create an extra `partial class` (separated file) for your `Form1` and place your cluttering methods there.

Or you could collapse them with `#region`

```
#region UI Handlers


#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

The perfect solution would be using some kind of MVVM for WinForms. In that case in your  ViewModel you can implement your business logic separately from the code-behind. 
Check out this: 
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/364485/mvvm-model-view-viewmodel-patte
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your Form class subsection. It most cases it is still a partial class. Create a new .cs file in the same subsection in your project and add another partial form class to it.

You can find additional information here:
[Partial Classes and Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can add a new class to your project (right-click the project in Solution Explorer --> Add Class --> ) and put your methods there. Then you will need to hook the methods up to the controls in code:

I added a static class called "Form Methods" and put a method in there for label1 Click event:

```
static class FormMethods
{
    public static void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label label = (Label) sender;

        // Try to find the textbox through the label's parent form
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox) label.Parent.Controls.Find("textBox1", true).First();

        if (textBox != null)
        {
            textBox.Select();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the Form Designer code, you can hook up the event:

```
this.label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(FormMethods.label1_Click);
```

Alternatively, you can make the class part of your original form class, and it will still be a separate file. If you want to do this, you can then make your event a private non-static method, and you would change the class definition to a public partial class:

```
public partial class Form1 // <-- This used to be: static class FormMethods
{
    // This used to be: public static void label1_Click
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        . . .
```

And then hooking up the event looks like:

```
this.label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(label1_Click);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I also have 2 additional questions:
1. Would this be regarded as more professional then just collapsing it with a #region? 
2. Is there an option of creating one method which would do something like "if textbox2 is changed, then change the value of a[2]
if textbox3 is changed, then change the value of a[3] etc "?

Because now I have 12 methods that handle 12 textboxes, is there a way to have just 1 method to handle all of them?

Comment: no, not more professional. only do it if it makes your life easier. And yes, you can create one method to handle them all. create the method and then hook up each controls event to that method.

Comment: I don't see the benefits of creating a static handler. It just makes it more difficult. It won't save memory.

Comment: I agree completely. @Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

You can create any number of partial class files mimicking your original and group methods inside as your functionally needs - however, you won't be able to use the designer to directly navigate to your callbacks. That is, if you double click a graphic element or click an event of a graphic element you will have an unexpected behavior: in both cases you will have an event handler generated in your first partial and a hook created to that . . . so you can't directly navigate to those handlers anymore, and you need to go trough your partial files looking for their definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `partial` to split C# code like this.

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }
}

public partial class Employee
{
    public void GoToLunch()
    {
    }
}
```